# Codeigniter - Data from view page gets erased after call to controller function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have just started learning codeigniter and have been working on creating a dummy Job Portal Application.
My default controller 'Home' loads data of list of jobs from database at first visit to the Page.
But Whenever I try to register a new user, the previous data from index page gets erased. I get an error message as "Message: Undefined variable: JOBS"
Even if there is a call to new controller function and the page gets redirected, the previous data for list of jobs gets deleted.

Below are my MVC from codeigniter Application.

My Controller

```
<?php
 class Home extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('HomeModel');

}

public function index() {

    $query = $this->HomeModel->getJobList();
    $data['JOBS'] = null;
    if ($query) {
        $data['JOBS'] = $query;
    }

    $this->load->view('index.php', $data);
}
public function new_user_registration() {
    // Check validation for user input in SignUp form
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Id / Username', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First Name', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last Name', 'trim|required');
    if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
        $this->load->view('index.php');
    } else {
        $user_data = array(
            'email_id' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'password' => md5($this->input->post('password')),
            'firstname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
            'lastname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
        );
        $result = $this->HomeModel->registration_insert($user_data);
        if ($result == true) {
            $data['message_display'] = 'Registration Successful !';
            $this->load->view('index.php', $data);
        } else {
            $data['message_display'] = 'Username already exist!';
            $this->load->view('index.php', $data);
        }
    }
}
}
?>
```

My Model

```
<?php
class HomeModel extends CI_Model {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function getJobList() {
        $query = $this->db->get('job_details');
        return $query->result();
    }
// Function to Insert registration data in database
    public function registration_insert($data) {
// Query to check whether username already exist or not
        $condition = "email_id =" . "'" . $data['email_id'] . "'";
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('user_profile');
        $this->db->where($condition);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
// Query to insert data in database
            $this->db->insert('user_profile', $data);
            if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

My Index.php Page

```
<?php
$this->load->view('header/header.php');
?>
<div class="modal fade" id="logIn" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Log In</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>
                            <form>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                            </form>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                Not Registered Yet... Click here to <a data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" href="#signUp">Sign Up !</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="signUp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">New User Registration</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>
                            <!-- <form>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                            </form> -->
                            <form action="Home/new_user_registration" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email">Email Id (Username): </label>
                                    <input name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Id" type="email" required="required">
                                    <div class="error_msg"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="password">Password: </label>
                                    <input name="password" id="password" class="form-control" type="password">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="fname">First Name: </label>
                                    <input name="fname" id="fname" class="form-control" type="text">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="lname">Last Name: </label>
                                    <input name="lname" id="lname" class="form-control" type="text">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign Up</button>
                            </form>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                Already Registered... Click here to <a data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" href="#logIn">Log In</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <?php
if (isset($message_display)) {
    echo "<div class='message'>";
    echo $message_display;
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
    <!-- <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2"><h3>Job Title</h3></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><h3>Job Description</h3></div>
                <div class="col-md-2"><h3>Experience Required</h3></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><h3>Skills Required</h3></div>
                <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div> -->
    <?php foreach ($JOBS as $job) {?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row bg-primary">
                <div class="col-md-6"><h4><?=$job->job_title;?></h4></div>
                <div class="col-md-6 text-right"><h5><?=$job->posting_date;?></h5></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-push-1 col-md-10"><h5><strong>Job Description: </strong></h5></div>
                <div class="col-md-push-2 col-md-10"><p><?=$job->job_desc;?></p></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-push-1 col-md-10"><h5><strong>Skills: </strong></h5></div>
                <div class="col-md-push-2 col-md-10"><p><?=$job->skills_required;?></p></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-push-1 col-md-4"><p><strong>Exp:&emsp;</strong><?=$job->exp_reqd;?></p></div>
                <div class="col-md-push-1 col-md-4"><p><strong>Salary:&emsp;</strong><?=$job->salary;?></p></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-right"><p><button class="btn btn-primary btn-toolbar">Apply</button></p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <?php }?>
</div>
<?php $this->load->view('footer/footer.php');?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error in your code. You are actually loading `index.php` view file you are not initializing `index()` function. Please check possible solutions describe below.

1. Once user has been successfully registered then redirect them to home page

   `redirect('home');`
2. As per your above code you are not redirecting user on home page, so in this case you need to pass data to your view, and you missed that. Please check below for the same.

   `if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
       // Your code 
   } else {
       if ($result == true) {
           $data['message_display'] = 'Registration Successful !';
           $query = $this->HomeModel->getJobList();
           $data['JOBS'] = null;
           if ($query) {
               $data['JOBS'] = $query;
           }
           $this->load->view('index.php', $data);
       } else {
           $data['message_display'] = 'Username already exist!';
           $this->load->view('index.php', $data);
       }
   }`

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: The second Solution worked perfectly. Although just for my knowledge i tried the first option as well using `redirect('Home','refresh');`, but the URL displayed `localhost/jobportal/Home/localhost/jobportal/Home`. can you please explain why this happened ?

Comment: Also when you said **_You have error in your code. You are actually loading index.php view file you are not initializing index() function._** What did you mean by this ? Sorry for asking naive question !

Comment: Si I mean instead of `$this->load->view('index.php', $data);` in your controller you can load `index` function like `$this->index();`.